# do-while loop within for is not wokirng

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, do-while

I got stuck in coding tic tac toe game. I need your help. Basically my question why my do-while loops do not work in my code in c++. I am using VS C++ 2015.

The basic logic behind is following;

1. create 3 by 3 array and put 1-9 as char.
2. set up a for loop and if statement to get players input X or O. if i is 0 or even it is player 1's turn to put X. if odd, player 2's turn to put O as char.
3. in the do-while loop, i want to check if players chose the already chosen cells or not. But the do-while loops seem not working at all.
4. check if there is 3 Xs or Os in a row by if statement.

Please let me know what is the key point to solve this...Thank you so much!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tic_tac_toe.h"

using namespace std;


int tic_tac_toe() {
    cout << "You chose tic tac toe game!:) \n";

    char t[] = { '1', '2' ,'3' , '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

    cout << "_" << t[0] << "_|_" << t[1] << "_|_" << t[2] << "_\n";
    cout << "_" << t[3] << "_|_" << t[4] << "_|_" << t[5] << "_\n";
    cout << " " << t[6] << " | " << t[7] << " | " << t[8] << " \n";


    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

        if (i == 0 || i % 2 == 0) {
            cout << "Player 1, your trun. Please choose a number to put X. \n";
            int n1;
            cin >> n1;

            do {
                cout << "You cannot overwrite on X or O. Please in put again. \n";
                cin >> n1;
            } while (t[n1 - 1] == 'X' || t[n1 - 1] == 'O');

            t[n1 - 1] = 'X';

        }
        else {
            cout << "Player 2, your trun. Please choose a number to put O. \n";
            int n2;
            cin >> n2;

            do {
                cout << "You cannot overwrite on X or O. Please in put again. \n";
                cin >> n2;
            } while (t[n2 - 1] == 'X' || t[n2 - 1] == 'O');

            t[n2 - 1] = 'O';

        }





        cout << "_" << t[0] << "_|_" << t[1] << "_|_" << t[2] << "_\n";
        cout << "_" << t[3] << "_|_" << t[4] << "_|_" << t[5] << "_\n";
        cout << " " << t[6] << " | " << t[7] << " | " << t[8] << " \n";

        if (t[0] == 'X' && t[1] == 'X' && t[2] == 'X' ||
            t[3] == 'X' && t[4] == 'X' && t[5] == 'X' || 
            t[6] == 'X' && t[7] == 'X' && t[8] == 'X' || 

            t[0] == 'X' && t[3] == 'X' && t[6] == 'X' || 
            t[1] == 'X' && t[4] == 'X' && t[7] == 'X' || 
            t[2] == 'X' && t[5] == 'X' && t[8] == 'X' ||

            t[0] == 'X' && t[4] == 'X' && t[7] == 'X' || 
            t[2] == 'X' && t[4] == 'X' && t[6] == 'X' ) {

            cout << "Player 1, you won! \n";
            break;

        }
        else if(t[0] == 'O' && t[1] == 'O' && t[2] == 'O' ||
                t[3] == 'O' && t[4] == 'O' && t[5] == 'O' ||
                t[6] == 'O' && t[7] == 'O' && t[8] == 'O' ||

                t[0] == 'O' && t[3] == 'O' && t[6] == 'O' ||
                t[1] == 'O' && t[4] == 'O' && t[7] == 'O' ||
                t[2] == 'O' && t[5] == 'O' && t[8] == 'O' ||

                t[0] == 'O' && t[4] == 'O' && t[7] == 'O' ||
                t[2] == 'O' && t[4] == 'O' && t[6] == 'O' )
        {
            cout << "Player 2, you won! \n";
            break;

        }



    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: "It's not working" is not really an information about what you expect and what actually happens. Giving this info would greatly increase your chance of getting help. For instance, I'd expect a `while` loop in place of your `do-while`, since you write "You cannot overwrite on X or O. Please in put again" after first choice, no matter what choice is it. However, I can't post it as answer, as I do not know if this is your actual problem

Comment: Do you know the difference between a `while` and a `do-while` loop? The full body of a `do-while` loop is executed at least once, because the condition is checked at the end. This means that you show the message asking for input, then you read the input with `cin`, then you enter the `do` loop, you immediately tell the player that the choice is wrong (without having checked it at all!), you ask him to enter a new value, and finally you check it. This is clearly wrong. Hint: what would happen, instead, if you used a `while` loop?

Comment: Note that the two branches of the `if` statement are nearly identical. Think about how to extract a function that does what each branch requires without doubling the code.

Comment: Thanks all, but while loop works the same way and does not prevent overwriting.

Comment: Oh Sorry, it worked! some mistakes on my end. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You should be using while instead do...while

Your code should be like this for first player

```
while (t[n1 - 1] == 'X' || t[n1 - 1] == 'O'){
    cout << "You cannot overwrite on X or O. Please in put again. \n";
    cin >> n1;
}
```

for second player,

```
while (t[n2 - 1] == 'X' || t[n2 - 1] == 'O'){
    cout << "You cannot overwrite on X or O. Please in put again. \n";
    cin >> n2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but its still not working as I expect. it does not print You cannot overwrite on X or O. Please input again. when we overwrite X on O or vice versa.

Comment: Oh Sorry, it worked! some mistakes on my end. Thanks a lot!